# meteor client-side tests hang on AWS but not locally

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor, amazon-ec2, nightmare

I'm trying to get my client side tests working for CI. Right now I'm just running them from a terminal - though eventually they will be running in Jenkins

On my dev machine (Ubuntu 14.04) the tests run just fine.
On my AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu 16.04.1) the tests client DO NOT run, the server tests run, then I get the log: `=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/` then nothing. The command I'm using is:

`MOCHA_REPORTER=tap SERVER_TEST_REPORTER=tap CLIENT_TEST_REPORTER=tap TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=nightmare xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha`

my npm and node versions are the same on both machines (3.10.9 and v4.6.2 respectively).

I'm using the segmentio/nightmare browser to run tests (as supported by dispatch:mocha) because I was having issues with selenium/chrome when testing locally. I use this specific version as recommended here (https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/224)

I'm using xvfb-run to run the headless browser. I tried the slightly different configuration recommended in the above link, but it also didn't work.

The commands I'm running locally vs on AWS are identical. The only difference I see between the two is the Ubuntu version - is this likely to be the problem, or have I overlooked something?

I'm pretty stuck on where to go from here - any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I spend hours looking, then 10 mins after I ask, I find the answer:

It seems like one of these installs fixed the issue - I guess AWS doesnt install X11 by default on their servers, which makes sense. The majority of the command (except xorg and openbox) came from here: https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/224

`sudo apt-get install -y xvfb x11-xkb-utils xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic x11-apps clang libdbus-1-dev libgtk2.0-dev libnotify-dev libgnome-keyring-dev libgconf2-dev libasound2-dev libcap-dev libcups2-dev libxtst-dev libxss1 libnss3-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib xorg openbox`